# What does the '@@' symbol mean in the output of nm command?

Tags: c++, linux, linker, shared-libraries, name-mangling

I'm looking at the output of 'nm' command for a shared lib in Linux. I see this

```
U stderr@@GLIBC_2.0
```

Does that mean stderr is hardlinked the glibc2.0? The reason I'm asking this we have a set of libraries (let's say a1.so, a2.so, ...) that are built against one of the different versions of our exported libraries (let's say ex.so.1, ex.so.2). The exported libraries all export a function, say foo. When the a*.so libraries are loaded, they somehow magically patch the appropriate functions inside the libraries they were built against. I see the output of nm for different libraries like below.

```
nm a1.so | grep foo
U foo@@ex.1

nm a2.so | grep foo
U foo@@ex.2
```

What role does the '@@' play here? I couldn't find any documentation about the '@@'. Any references would be helpful.

Comment: It's the symbol version. A library like glibc may contain several versions of the same symbol.

Comment: Section 3 of [this](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) paper by Ulrich Drepper goes into more detail.

Comment: Thanks @n.m. and Brett Hale. I will go through the paper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@` allows specifying a version for a symbol. When multiple definitions of a symbol exist, they'd have different versions. To indicate the default version, `@@` is used. The default version is chosen if no explicit version is specified.

More details can be found in the [binutils VERSION documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/VERSION.html) (search for "`@@`").